# Gulp not working - gulp: command not found

Tags: node.js, gulp

```
warmachine@HH-00 MINGW64 /c/HTML5/app (dev)

$ gulp -v
bash: gulp: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it *globally* if you want to use it like that:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Alternatively using Yarn:

```
yarn add global gulp
```

In both cases you need to have the NPM/Yarn globals path in `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Uninstall previous Gulp installation and related packages, if any
$ npm rm gulp -g
$ npm rm gulp-cli -g
$ cd [your-project-dir/]
$ npm rm gulp --save-dev
$ npm rm gulp --save
$ npm rm gulp --save-optional
$ npm cache clean # for npm < v5

# Install the latest Gulp CLI tools globally
$ npm install -g gulp

# Install Gulp 4 into your project as dev dependency
$ npm install gulp --save-dev

# Check the versions installed. Make sure your versions are not lower than shown.
$ gulp -v
---
[10:48:35] CLI version 2.0.1
[10:48:35] Local version 4.0.0
```